# AssertionError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I made a Python program to loop through a csv file of data and produce a new csv file. In order to reduce runtime I tried using numba, below is my code:

```
import csv
import timeit
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def main():
    file = open("test_data.csv","r")
    newfile = open("rewrite5_gpu_output.csv",'w', newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(newfile)
    dataframe = []
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    for line in file:
        new_line = []
        line = line.split(",")
        for item in line:
            if item == '\n':
                pass
            elif item == "active":
                new_line.append(1) # 1 = active p53
            elif item == "inactive":
                new_line.append(0) # 0 = inactive p53
            else:
                try:
                    item = item.strip('\n')
                    item = float(item)
                    new_line.append(item)
                except:
                    pass
        dataframe.append(new_line)
        #print(new_line)
    writer.writerows(dataframe)
    newfile.close()
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print('Time: ', stop - start)

main()
```

However, I get the error:

```
AssertionError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)
SETUP_EXCEPT(arg=32, lineno=23)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment out "try:" and "except:".
In some other post I have read that try - except is not supported by numba.jit
and it worked in my python script.

br,